# Windows Server connection using putty

Tags: windows-server-2012, ssh-tunnel, putty

Iam having hard time connecting to an Azure Windows Server 2012 from my institution (University). The goal is to connect to the SQL Server that runs on this Windows server

This is the strange situation:

From my house, i connect with RDP, ssh and sql management studio fine, with no problem.

From the institution, i can connect only with RDP!! The other to ways are not working.

I asked the network administrator and told me that they are not using any filtering at all. I wonder then...whose problem is this?

To give an example, when I try to connect with ssh (putty), I get the following screen.

[Putty login process error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBzyt.png)

Just after i type the password, the screen pauses and nothing happens.

The client runs Windows 10.
The server runs windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you reached a key rejection message proves out the transport piece.

Hop over to the server via rdp and read your sshd or security logs to see what is happening.

If I were to guess, I'd say it is either a reverse lookup taking forever, or some hiccup loading up the shell and env (not as likely but worth checking).